# How to disable the <select> elements in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a some problem about disabling the `<select>`'s in DIV tags.

This is an calendar script, i use it for disableing some `<div>`'s, which i used for selecting the time, after chossing the date.

I have disabled the time selection in some dates, but disabled div elements stayed enabled.

This is code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var startDate;
var endDate;
var ONEDAY = 3600 * 24;

function resetDates() {
startDate = endDate = null;
}

function filterDates1(cal) {
startDate = cal.date.getTime();
/* If they haven't chosen an 
end date before we'll set it to the same date as the start date This
way if the user scrolls in the start date 5 months forward, they don't
need to do it again for the end date.
*/

if (endDate == null) { 
    var day29 = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    var day30 = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    var day31 = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    var day32 = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    var day33 = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    var day34 = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    var day35 = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
        if(day29 == "29/12/2011")
        {
            document.getElementById("hours").className = "show";
            document.getElementById("hours1").className = "hide";

            document.getElementById("hours3").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours4").className = "hide";
        }
        else if(day30 == "30/12/2011")
        {
            document.getElementById("hours").className = "show";
            document.getElementById("hours1").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours3").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours4").className = "hide";
        }
        else if(day31 == "31/12/2011")
        {
            document.getElementById("hours").className = "show";
            document.getElementById("hours1").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours3").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours4").className = "hide";
        }
        else if(day32 == "01/01/2012")
        {
            document.getElementById("hours").className = "show";
            document.getElementById("hours1").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours3").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours4").className = "hide";
        }
                                    else if(day33 == "02/01/2012")
        {
            document.getElementById("hours").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours1").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours3").className = "show";
            document.getElementById("hours4").className = "hide";
        }
                                    else if(day34 == "03/01/2012")
        {
            document.getElementById("hours").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours1").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours3").className = "show";
            document.getElementById("hours4").className = "hide";
        }
                                    else if(day35 == "04/01/2012")
        {
            document.getElementById("hours").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours1").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours3").className = "show";
            document.getElementById("hours4").className = "hide";
        }

        else
        {
            document.getElementById("hours1").className = "show";
            document.getElementById("hours").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours3").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("hours4").className = "hide";
        }

}
endDate = date.getTime();
}


/*
* This functions return true to disallow a date
* and false to allow it.
*/



/* 
* Can't choose days before today or before the
* end date
*/
function disallowDateBefore(date) {
date = date.getTime();
if ((startDate != null) && (date < (startDate - ONEDAY))) {
//start date can't be prior to end date
return true; 
} 
var now = new Date().getTime();
if (date < (now - ONEDAY)) {
//start date can't be prior to today
return true;
}

return false;
}

/* 
* Can't choose days before today or before the
* start date
*/
function disallowDateAfter(date) {
date = date.getTime();
if ((endDate != null) && (date > (endDate - ONEDAY))) {
//end date can't be before start date
return true;
} 

var now = new Date().getTime();
if (date < (now - ONEDAY)) {
//end date can't be prior to today
return true;
}
return false;
}

// end hiding contents from old browsers  -->



var cal = new Zapatec.Calendar.setup({

inputField     :    "sel1",   // id of the input field
button         :    "button1",  // What will trigger the popup of the calendar
ifFormat       :    "%d/%m/%Y",       //  of the input field: Mar 18, 2005
showsTime      :     false,          //no time
dateStatusFunc    :    disallowDateAfter, //the function to call
onUpdate       :    filterDates1

}); 

//]]></script>




<style>
.hide
{
    display: none; visibility:hidden;
}
.show
{
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

But in this code, how i can FULL disable NOT ACTIVE divs?

thank you!!!

Comment: You can't "disable" a div, you can disable individual select elements by setting their disabled property to true:

Comment: Please try to post concise code samples. This makes it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: I have 3 <DIVS> and Time-Date fields:

When user choosed Ex. 31.12.2001 The time Select tag is disabled, and enabled other time selection form, BUT every time when user choosed  31.12.2011  and in OTHER div's choosed Ex. 12.00 - 16.00, it's send me the values of the FIRST div's included <Select> values :(

Comment: If you don't want the values of selects be sent to your server when you submit the request, you will have to remove completely the div from the form before submitting it (you can listen for the "submit" event on the form). But this kind of logic would be better on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Find the hidden divs, and loop through their children and disable them.

The following function lets you specify the parent of your divs (could be `document` or some containing `form` or `div`), the tagName of elements with a certain className, and a flag to say whether to enable or disable their children:

```
function disableOrEnableChildren(rootElement, tagName, className, disable) {
   var els = rootElement.getElementsByTagName(tagName),
       i, j,
       r = new RegExp("(^| )" + className + "( |$)"),
       c;
   for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
      if (r.test(els[i].className)) {
         c = els[i].childNodes;
         for (j =0; j < c.length; j++)
            if (typeof c.disabled != "undefined")
                c.disabled = disable;
      }
}

disableOrEnableChildren(document, "div", "hide", true);

disableOrEnableChildren(document, "div", "show", false);
```

(Of course you could make that shorter if you make it less generic.)

Note: unrelated to your question, the big if / else if / else if structure at the beginning of your code can be reduced to a much smaller structure by combining some of the cases:

```
    if(day29 == "29/12/2011" ||
       day30 == "30/12/2011" ||
       day31 == "31/12/2011" ||
       day32 == "01/01/2012")
    {
        document.getElementById("hours").className = "show";
        document.getElementById("hours1").className = "hide";
        document.getElementById("hours3").className = "hide";
        document.getElementById("hours4").className = "hide";
    }
    else if(day33 == "02/01/2012" ||
            day34 == "03/01/2012" ||
            day35 == "04/01/2012")
    {
        document.getElementById("hours").className = "hide";
        document.getElementById("hours1").className = "hide";
        document.getElementById("hours3").className = "show";
        document.getElementById("hours4").className = "hide";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("hours1").className = "show";
        document.getElementById("hours").className = "hide";
        document.getElementById("hours3").className = "hide";
        document.getElementById("hours4").className = "hide";
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR ANSWER SIR>>>!!!! this is a code.. It it true? – 
www.amanor.ru/amanor.txt

Comment: And please tell me, what i must change in your fisrt function script for it's working?